# How many transactions are submitted to transaction pool per second?

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions, mining-pools, txpool

As the title, is there any statistics about how many transactions are submitted to the transaction pool per second?
Note that this is different from the number of transactions processed by Ethereum.

Comment: http://ethviewer.live/ Shown in the bottom left. Pool size rather than /s. May or may not be accurate. You'd really want to run your own node with the pool size config set to a very large value (e.g. `--txpool.globalslots` in Geth), and calculate yourself.

Comment: Thanks. That's a very useful website with interesting animations.